# How do I wire a 3 gang switch in my new bath?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I am putting a basement bath in and I need help. I will be adding a new 20 amp circuit for the single pole outlet. Also, a 20 amp line for a 3 switch box. Switch #1 is for the vanity light, #2 is for the exhaust fan light and #3 is for the exhaust fan.

I would appreciate a drawing showing from the 3 gang box the wiring of the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

The following diagram should help you to visualize how to wire up the three switches. In your case you may have 12 AWG wire due to the 20A circuit. Also you will substitute one of the lights with the blower fan motor connection.

[image]

Picture Credit: [Taken from this web page.](http://www.justanswer.com/home-improvement/142hg-wire-three-switches-three-gang-box.html)

Comment: Do I have to stay with 12/2 wire for the switch and fixture connections since I have a 12/2 (20amp) A.F.C.I. breaker line as the power line coming into the 3 gang box ?

Comment: You can use 12/3 to feed the exhaust fan, since you'll share the neutral at the fan.  Black will be switched hot for light, Red switched hot for the fan.

Comment: @Larry - If you bring 12/2 wire into the box as the power feed you should continue the use of 12AWG wire to all branches off the feed circuit.

Comment: @MichaelKaras But the fixture wires are only 14 AWG, would you have to rewire the fixtures if you're using 20A and 12 AWG?

Comment: @Tester101 - The need to carry the 12 AWG wire through the ganged switch box is because the circuit is circuit breakered at 20A. If the wiring pigtails on the blower fixture are only 14 AWG then I would say to just connect them to the 12AWG wire fed up to the blower electrical enclosure.

Comment: Would I be better running 14/2 wire from the breaker with a 15 amp breaker into the switch gang box and then using 14/2 wire to connect all fixtures ?

Comment: @Larry - You can do that as long as the load of the lights and the blower fan does not demand current flow in excess of what is recommended for a 14/2 15A circuit. Recommended max load on a circuit breaker is normally 80% of the circuit breaker rating. So for a 15A circuit that would be a maximum load of 12A.

Comment: to be sure I am within the max load limit then I guess I will stay with the 20amp 12/2 feed into the box and run 12/2 wire to all the fixtures. I have a lot of 12/2 wire available.